# Numpy - Array how to reshape it

Tags: python

I have stored classes in array [0,1] is class for negative and [1,0] is class for positive values now i want to reshape it.

my input array is like this

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

and i am trying to reshape it like this

```
ponlabel=np.array(ponlabel)
PositiveorNegativeLabel = ponlabel.reshape(24, 1)
print(PositiveorNegativeLabel)
```

getting error cannot reshape size 48 into (24,1)

Comment: Can you add what your expected outcome would be for your reshape?  Currently the shape is `(24,2)` so `(24,1)` would be a smaller array which is why the error is happening.  If you are simply wanting a 0 for negative class and 1 for positive class a list comprehension may be the way to go `[x[0] for x in ponlabel]`

Comment: You are turning a list of lists into an array. The new array will pick out all the items and, in this case, make a (24, 2). Your list is being interpreted by numpy as a (24,2) array of ints. Do you want to keep it as a (24,1) array of lists?

Comment: i want to keep as (24,1) array of list

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to extract only the first value use:

```
ponlabel[:, 0]
#array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

The same would apply for second value:

```
ponlabel[:, 1]
#array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me what you need, could you be more specific?
is it maybe something like this:

```
a=[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]==[0,1]:
            b.append(False)
        else:
            b.append(True)
```

with b like:

```
[False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```